# Save text into txtfile using actionscript 3 without asking directory path from user

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to save a string into .txt file using action script 3 ,I use this code :

```
var fileRef:FileReference;

fileRef = new FileReference();
fileRef.save("sasa", "saveFile.txt");
```

But this code asks the user the path location but i don't want to do it ,i need to save in the current directory of swf file without asking path from user?

Any ideas will be appreciated

I am so new in AS3

Best regards

Comment: use `File` instead of `FileReference`

Comment: @DodgerThud it doesn't work

Comment: if it's a web project you will never be able to save anything without the user knowledge and consent, if it's an AIR project use FileStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that for security reasons. But if you're doign an AIR app you can use [FileStream class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html)

Comment: As mentioned before all file access operations in Flash Player have to go through the user for security reasons. So you can not avoid the Save As box in your actionscript project.